# I want schedule timer with repeat count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to invoke a method 24 times but between each invocation I want an interval of 1 sec,
now am using

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(loadNumber) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

but how to count invocations, I want to invalidate timer after 24 count can I invalidate that.

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance variable for an `int`, it doesn't matter what you call it. Set it to "0" before you call the timer.

```
someInt = 0;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(loadNumber:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

In the action that the time calls check the value of this number to make sure the action should be performed and increment the number.

```
- (void)loadNumber:(NSTimer *)sender
{
    if (someInt <= 24) {
        //do something
        someInt ++;
    }else{
        [sender invalidate];
        someInt = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as a personal quirk, I don't like making instance variables for such small purposes, so instead I would pass the number into userInfo as an NSNumber (another way you can accomplish the same goal).

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a counter in `loadNumber`, which will invalidate your `NSTimer` after your desired repeat counts.